# nested loop to get output of 1 - space - 1, 2 - space, 1,2,3 if input is 3 (java)

Tags: java

Say I have user input 1, the output should be

1

if the input 2, the output should be:

1

12

If the input is 3, the output should be

1

12

123

I keep trying but cannot figure out how to do it help please

Comment: @Old-School java, ive tried some stuff but it's not working lol need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter n: ");
      int n = sc.nextInt();

      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("" + j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(); //newline       

  }
}
```

Comment: do u know how to do it in java?

Comment: This will produce a wrong result. Numbers from 1 to n will be printed.

Comment: yeah this is not producing the output i was hoping for :(

Comment: sorry, I just modified the code to give the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use a single for-loop. Use an array to store the previous numbers and output them along with the current number.

```js
var userInput = 10;

var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
  document.write(numbers + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: can u give me an example?